# Internal and external storage for a FPGA

Tags: usb, fpga, ram, storage

I want to store at least 2Mbits on a FPGA. What is the normal practice for storing data on a FPGA internally?

Also, if I wanted to store 4GBytes externally, how would I go about doing this? Is it possible for a FPGA to read directly from a USB drive?

Comment: FPGA block RAM is fairly "expensive" in that getting a lot of it may drive you into a more expensive chip with more logic elements as well.  To have a meaningful question, you'll need to explain what you want the FPGA design to do with the memory. Both external DDR RAM and external flash are not unknown.  An USB drive could be used, but essentially always requires a processor core, either a hard or soft core inside the FPGA, or cooperating outside it.  The fixed-function USB mass storage *host* chips actually contain processors inside...

Comment: Welcome to the site. I think if you are asking the first question, you may possibly be over your head.

Comment: Is the internal storage meant to be volatile or non-volatile?

Comment: For the 4 GBytes externa, does this need to be removable? If it doesn't need to be removable, a Flash chip is simpler than a USB interface to a Flash.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful about what FPGA resources you are using.

I'm going to use Xilinx FPGA terminology, but other manufacturers have similar concepts with different names...

Xilinx FPGA are composed of slices of configurable logic. Basically each slice is a Look Up Table (LUT) and a Register (D Flip Flop). Different FPGA families have different sizes and configurations of these slices. If you just instantiate a bunch of memory cells, by default it wants to use up one bit per slice -- not very efficient... Xilinx added Block RAM to their Spartan-3 FPGA to give a place to implement "large" blocks of memory without consuming lots of valuable LUT Registers.

What you're seeking is a large System-on-Chip with big dedicated (non-configurable) memory. Maybe something like the Zynq XC7020 series? That product is a little bit of FPGA (Xilinx series 7 Atrix i think but don't quote me on that) plus some on-chip memory plus a dual-core Arm CPU. That system-on-chip also has some kind of USB interface I think. Not sure if it does what you need, but that's the kind of thing you seem to be wanting.

That said, product recommendations are out of scope for stackexchange network, so all I can say is that's an example of the kind of thing you might need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're going with this question. FPGAs usually have block rams that allow them to store data. However, the main purpose of an FPGA is not data storage but mostly parallel processing/glue logic/fast decision logic blocks, etc.

For your second answer, there are probably FPGA cores for USB interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to store at least 2Mbits on a FPGA. What is the normal practice
> for storing data on a FPGA internally?

FPGAs can store bulk temporary data in their block RAM cells.  Typical cells are one or two KB in size.  Many FPGAs contain hundreds of block RAMs.

For example...

- Xilinx XC7A50T FPGA has 150 block RAMs and can store up to 2.7M-Bits of data in them.
- Xilinx SC7A200T FPGA has 385 block RAMs and can store up to 13.1M-Bits of data in them.
  https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds180_7Series_Overview.pdf

> Also, if I wanted to store 4GBytes externally, how would I go about
> doing this? Is it possible for a FPGA to read directly from a USB
> drive?

If you want removable storage an SD card is going to be considerably simpler than USB.

- The majority of FPGAs don't include USB interface hardware and would need a separate physical layer driver chip.  One exception would be some SoC FPGAs such as Xilinx ZYNQ.
- SD cards just use a SPI bus and CMOS IO levels, which can be directly interfaced to the IO of most FPGAs.
- The firmware required to work with USB devices is more complex than for SD cards.

If you want the 4GBytes "external" storage to be part of the circuit card then you have a few main options.

Micron corporation makes NAND flash chips up to several GB in size.  For example...

- MT29F32G08CBADBWP-12IT:D , 32G-bits, Parallel, NAND Flash, priced around $4 each in quantity.
- MT29F128G08CBCEBJ4-37ITR:E, 128G-bits, Parallel, NAND Flash, priced around $9 each in quantity.

Buy an EMMC drive chip.  EMMC has the lowest cost per bit.  Internally they use NAND flash, but also include a controller that manages the flash.  You can get sizes up to several terra-bits.  Examples include...

Kioxia, THGBMNG5D1LBAIL, 4G-Bytes, eMMC, around $5 each
https://www.mouser.com/specsheets/KIOXIA_Consumer_Grade_e_MMC.pdf

Kioxia, THGBMJG6C1LBAIL, 8G-Bytes, eMMC, around $7 each
https://www.mouser.com/specsheets/KIOXIA_Consumer_Grade_e_MMC.pdf

SanDisk, SDINBDG4-8G, 8G-Bytes, eMMC, around $10 each
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/669/SanDisk_10092017_iNAND-7250-Industrial-Brochure-1217090.pdf

Kioxia, THGAMRT0T43BAIR, 128G-Bytes, eMMC, around $50 each
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/1034/Kioxia_America_Inc_Consumer_Grade_e_MMC-1879685.pdf